# Django: Accessing URL variables in Class Based Views and Forms

Tags: django, django-views

I'm trying to create an object in Django using the standard class based views and form libraries.  Three fields in my form are dependent upon a domain variable captured from the URL pattern.  My questions are:

- How do I access `domain` within `CreateSubscription` so that I can set `Subscription.site` to `Site.objects.filter(domain=domain)[0]`?
- How do I limit the dropdown fields rendered from `CreateSubscriptionForm` so that `plan` displays only `SubscriptionPlan.objects.filter(site=Site.objects.filter(domain=domain)[0])` and `payment_profile` is limited to `PaymentProfile.objects.filter(user=request.user)`?

For clarity's sake, the domain in `r'^subscribe/(?P<domain>\w+\.\w+)/$'` is unrelated to my own site's domain.  The `django.contrib.sites` framework won't help me here.

Thanks in advance for helping me untangle all of these CBV methods.  :)

The URL pattern is:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from accounts.views import *

url(r'^subscribe/(?P<domain>\w+\.\w+)/$', 
    CreateSubscription.as_view(), name='subscribe_to_site'),
)
```

The view in question is:

```
from accounts.forms import *
from accounts.models import *

class CreateSubscription(CreateView):
    model = Subscription
    form_class = CreateSubscriptionForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super(CreateSubscription, self).form_valid(form)
```

The relevant models are:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
from django.db import models

class PaymentProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)

class SubscriptionPlan(models.Model):
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

class Subscription(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site)
    plan = models.ForeignKey(SubscriptionPlan)
    payment_profile = models.ForeignKey(PaymentProfile)
```

And, finally, my form is:

```
from accounts.models import *

class CreateSubscriptionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Subscription
        exclude = ('user', 'site', )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the data passed to the view, use `self.args` and `self.kwargs`

```
from accounts.forms import *
from accounts.models import *

class CreateSubscription(CreateView):
    model = Subscription
    form_class = CreateSubscriptionForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        form.instance.site = Site.objects.get(domain=self.kwargs['domain'])
        return super(CreateSubscription, self).form_valid(form)
```

To restrict the dropdown content, you need to set the `queryset` for those fields. Very basically, something along these lines:

```
class CreateSubscriptionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    plan = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=SubscriptionPlan.objects.filter(xxx)
    )

    ...

    class Meta:
        model = Subscription
        exclude = ('user', 'site', )
```

This can also be done inside the view so that you have access to the domain.

```
class CreateSubscription(CreateView):
    model = Subscription
    form_class = CreateSubscriptionForm

    def get_form(self, form_class):
        """
        Returns an instance of the form to be used in this view.
        """
        form = super(CreateSubscription, self).get_form(form_class)
        form.fields['plan'].queryset = SubscriptionPlan.objects.filter(site__domain=self.kwargs['domain'])
        return form

    ...

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        form.instance.site = Site.objects.get(domain=self.kwargs['domain'])
        return super(CreateSubscription, self).form_valid(form)
```